# Print Log4CXX exception stacktrace

Tags: c++, logging, log4cxx

Using Log4CXX_ERROR I can only print e.what().

```
catch (const std::exception e)
{
    logger->error("exception:" << e.what());
    //logger->error("exception:" << e); //not allowed
}
```

How can I print exception stack trace using log4cxx?

Answer (score 1):

First Add a handler function:

```
void trace() {
    void *array[20];
    size_t size;

    /* store up to 20 return address of the current program state in array
       and return the exact number of values stored */
    size = (size_t)backtrace(array, 20);

    /* return names of functions from the backtrace list in array and
       write result immediately to stderr */
    backtrace_symbols_fd(array, size, STDERR_FILENO);
}
```

and, then call this function to dump stack trace on stderr.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as to how to log them using log4cxx